# Is it possible to use soaplib server with Apache?

Tags: python, web-services, soaplib

Almost every documentation I am seeing shows Soaplib servers to be deployed using Cherry Py or some other server. Instead of that can be be deployed using apache?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`soaplib` makes its servers be WSGI applications, so they can be deployed in any WSGI environment.  Best way to use WSGI on Apache is [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/).